# Get available memory using PID in Linux/C and save it in a variable

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

At the top of my C program, I get the process ID and store it in a variable pid:

```
pid_t pid;
pid = getpid();
```

Using that PID (in this case, 21834), I want to get the available memory for that process and store it in a variable.  There are many ways to show memory usage from the terminal, but I need a way to get it under program control and store the result to a variable for further computation.

I also get the program_invocation_name, which is the process name:

```
extern char *program_invocation_name;
extern char *program_invocation_short_name;
```

Now that I have the process id and process name, how can I get the available memory for the process and store it in a variable?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean with available memory for the process? In what way do you expect available memory to depend on the process?

Comment: As I understand it, each process has memory available to it, depending on how much that process has used.  All of the command line methods I have seen use the PID or process name.  If you have a way for me to get available memory under program control, please let me know.

Comment: So are you referring to the memory that is _currently_ allocated to the process, rather than what it _could_ request from the kernel?

Comment: I am looking for the amount it could request from the kernel.  That will depend on how much the process has used.

Comment: No, it usually depends only on how much memory is still free on the system or can be repurposed by the kernel and in typical configurations Linux overcommits memory as well.

Comment: Okay, but I'm looking for a dependable way to know how much I can request.

Comment: There is no 100% reliable way in Linux except if your process is the only one running on the system. Another process can always take all memory before you can request any.

Comment: There are no other processes, other than the essential Linux processes, that run while this particular program runs.  It's a mission-critical program, so we don't run it alongside other processes.  There may still not be a 100% reliable method, but I'll settle for the highest percentage probability.

Comment: Even if you think your process is the "only" one, you have no way to avoid Linux cloning thread(s) to do things under the covers that suck up more resources (even temporarily).  About all you can do here is to try to allocate as much as possible until you succeed, then promptly release it and remember the amount that worked (once).  But you could still see erratic system operation from doing that - so do it and remember 80% or 90% of the amount, and then test how well your embedded system works with that.